# How can i add a StatefulWidget class into a the BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to add a StatefulWidget class into a BottomNavigationBar, so you have StatefulWidget in the BottomNavigationBarItem.

I tried it with some Tutorials, but they al had a StatelessWidget.

What i expect is to make a Counter ++ and a Counter -- in other BottomNavigatioBarItems.

Comment: Add some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use stateful widgets if you used the BottomAppBar widget

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom App Bar')),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {},),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {},),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Still , with the BottomAppBar i get the same               error: The element type 'Page1' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. (list_element_type_not_assignable at [flutter_tabapp_app] lib/main.dart:81)